# Hide root node and edges in D3 v4 Tree Diagram

Tags: d3.js

For the following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/intelligence_ai/xu90srxz/) I'd like to hide the root node. Any help is appreciated, to view the code please view the fiddle.

I imagine I would do something like the following but I'm unsure of how/where to implement it:

```
if (d.depth > 0) {
 ...node is drawn
}
```

Image below:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean "hide",  as it's in DOM, but not visible?  For that you could give nodes with depth 0 a certain class, and set the class's visibility. 
Or if you mean "not drawn", as it's not in the DOM, at all, you could .filter your selection before appending circles etc.

Comment: Thanks @TomShanley, I would like to 'not draw' it. How could I modify the code to use .filter?
// Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

Comment: What Gerardo said :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Not drawing it* is not "drawing it with zero opacity" or "hidden display". It's actually *not appending* the element.

Therefore, the simplest option is removing it from the data array. Just filter out the first node:

```
nodes = nodes.filter(function(d){
    return d.depth != 0;
})
```

As `0` is falsy, this is the same of:

```
nodes = nodes.filter(function(d){
    return d.depth;
})
```

And also filter out all links from it:

```
links = links.filter(function(d){
    return d.depth != 1;
})
```

Here is your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wa21csbc/

Also, since those elements are not painted anymore, you can move the dataviz to the left, thus occupying the empty SVG space. That space is there because we're filtering out the first node **after** `d3.tree()` calculated the positions.

Comment: thank you, I posted a follow up question if you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282595/d3-v4-tree-diagram-show-first-node-at-top-of-svg-and-be-able-to-scroll-down